# PHP connection error

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP, I am trying to implement network communication with mysql database which I made through phpmyadmin over my Bluehost account. Now I have written the following php script to check whether I can connect but I am not able to connect:

```
          <?php  
          $mysql_host='localhost';
          $mysql_user='xxx';
          $mysql_pass ='xxx';


          mysql_connect ('localhost', '$mysql_user', '$mysql_pass')
          or die ('I cannot connect to the database.');
           //echo 'hello';

          ?>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: remove quotes around variables - mysql_connect ('localhost', $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)

Comment: My Question is that I am not able to understand where I might be going wrong, any suggestions? Please bear with me as I am new to PHP.

Comment: mysql_connect ('localhost', $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)

Comment: Hey @Waygood thanks mate :) I am able to connect now!

Comment: [My advice would be don't learn `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained and the deprecation process has begun, see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql-connect). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli); [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: vascowhite, I am trying to learn PHP purely to develop mobile applications, it would be helpful if you suggest in context of Mobile Applications. I am not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: @Borniet explains why, and move towards pdo or mysqli like vascowhite suggests

Comment: The only regret is the downvoting, I specified that I am new to this!

Comment: Why do people compete with each other to give a vote down?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mysql_connect ('localhost', $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)
```

Instead of:

```
mysql_connect ('localhost', '$mysql_user', '$mysql_pass')
```

You do not need single quotes here.

Answer (score 1):

Variables between single quotes are not evaluated

```
 mysql_connect ('localhost', '$mysql_user', '$mysql_pass')
```

Try this:

```
  mysql_connect ('localhost', $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)
```

Answer (score 1):

the quotes make your vars to a string!
and never post you pass and user... even its local
use

```
mysql_connect ( $mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
```

dont use `die()`, use a error log.

better would be a pdo connection, it give you more comfort and securety.

make shure pdo is enadbled in mysql config, mostly it is enabled by default.

you can set up a pdo connection like

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=<databasename>;host=<hostname>';
  $user = '<user>';
  $password = '<passwd>';

try {                                                                         
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $_SESSION['error'] .= 'Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove quotes around variables in `mysql_connect`:

```
mysql_connect ('localhost', $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should understand diff bet single quotes and double quotes in php.
single quotes output string as it is. and double quotes parse string before outputting.